# Why I am not able to update to the lastest iOS Cordova Platform?

Tags: ios, cordova, npm, cordova-cli

I need to update my iOS app created with Cordova to last version but something is not clear:

```
cordova -v
```

returns: "4.2.0"

```
cordova platform list
```

returns: "Installed platforms: ios 3.7.0"

If i try to run:

```
cordova platform update ios
```

I get: "iOS project is now at version 3.7.0"

If i try to run:

```
cordova platform add ios@4.0
```

I get:
Error: No compatible version found: cordova-ios@'>=4.0.0-0 <4.1.0-0'
Valid install targets:
["3.5.0","3.6.0","3.6.1","3.6.3","3.7.0"]

so, what is the last platform available for iOS? 3.7.0?

Why Cordova gives instructions on how to update to 4.0.0 then? ([Upgrading iOS](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_upgrade.md.html#Upgrading%20iOS))

Thank you!

Comment: what's your Xcode version?

Comment: Have you tried updating Cordova first? `sudo npm update -g cordova`

Comment: @AtanuCSE I have the last stable version of xCode, 6.1.1. I am not using beta otherwise I would not be able to submit the app to the Apple Store.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes, firstly i have uninstall and reinstalled cordova as you said. It's correctly installed 4.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there is now fragmentation in Cordova versions. `4.2.0` is the Cordova CLI version.

As the `Valid Install Targets` suggests, `3.7.0` is the latest iOS version of Cordova.

Comment: Thank you, I have just found the same answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, It looks a bit confusing but the version of the Cordova CLI does not necessarily follows the versions of the platforms.

As you can see here:
Cordova CLI last version is 4.3.0 => [Cordova CLI](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-cli.git;a=summary)

iOS Platform last version is 3.8.0 => [Cordova iOS Platform](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=summary)

Android Platform last version is 3.7.1 => [Cordova Android Platform](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=summary)